# Deadlocks in sql server between SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: java, sql-server

In our system, we have two database tables one for EMAIL and EMAIL_ATTACHMENTS. There is a service, which checks this table frequently to send emails. There is a flag in EMAIL table which tells the service whether it can be picked up to send email. If there is an attachment, we will insert a record in EMAIL table, get the primary key and then insert all the attachments in the EMAIL_ATTACHMENTS and **finally turn the flag ON in the EMAIL table**, so that email service will pick up once inserts are completed in both tables, otherwise email service would pick the record before email attachments finished.

There is a window service, will check the EMAIL table for any records which it needs to send email. So one process is taking top 50 records and other one is inserting. I guess this causes the deadlock. How to avoid this situation?

1. Insert new email to be sent in EMAIL table and get the primary key of the record.
2. If attachment is there, then insert all attachments one by one for the id got it step 1
3. Enable flag in EMAIL table so that it can be picked by email service.

Comment: Is the insertion process running in a transaction?

Comment: this question is impossible to understand - can you provide some code?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, yes, there is insertion process. Whenever there is new email, we do inserts.

Comment: @RobEvans, I have updated the steps.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply solve this issue adding Read Uncommitted at the top of the SELECT method.
In this way your select don't need to wait the UPDATE statement and you will not have Deadlock issue anymore.

Please, try to add this into SELECT at the top of the query:
SET TRANSATION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

This will solve your deadlock issue

I hope it can be useful for you,
Best regards

Comment: But won't this read the records from EMAIL table, before attachments are inserted, then email service will not pick all of them properly.

Comment: If you have at least one record in attachments table, you can use iner join and send email only if you have a row also into attachments. If you can have an email without rows in attachments table maybe you can send email inserted only X seconds before start of the service, it can be a solution.Another solution is manage that with status: when you are inserting a row into email, you can use status "updating", you insert all the attachments and finally update status flag to "ready to Send". Your service will send only email in "ready to send" status and after that update to "sent" status.

Comment: Managing that with status column, adding Read Uncommitted, you will not have anymore deadlock and will send only really ready email. Sound it good?

Comment: Is it OK Manoj?